# Problems with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: objective-c, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I want to show a simple Tab Bar on the top of my main window.
This is the code I have used:

```
UIView* tabBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
tabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

  [self.view addConstraint:
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tabBar
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view 
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:0
                                    constant:0]];
  [self.view addConstraint:
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tabBar 
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  multiplier:1.0f
                                    constant:0]];
  [self.view addConstraint:
      [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tabBar
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  multiplier:1.0f
                                    constant:40]];
```

However the Tab Bar fails to show up. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the tab bar to the view, in this code at least. You also haven't specified a horizontal *position* (you have a width, but not a location, so the view will be halfway off the edge of the screen).

Visual format language would make this easier to set up: horizontal would be `@"|[tabBar]|"`, and vertical would be `@"V:|[tabBar(==40)]"`. You only need to use the long winded individual constraints method for things that can't be handled by VFL.

Answer (score 0):

i found three mistake:

1.before adding any constraints you need add view in views hierarchy.

```
tabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

2.First constraint multipler == 0 its tell tabBar.width == 0 points;

3.last constraint want looks like.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tabBar
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:nil
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                  multiplier:1.0f
                                    constant:40]];
```

Or just use constraintsWithVisualFormat method as advised @jrturton.